# vbCrLf creates unwanted "box" character in comment

Tags: vba, excel

Note: The following issue occurred in Excel 2010 but not in Excel 2013.

Using the VBA constant `vbCrLf` (ASCII code 10 and 13) to implement carriage return & line feed in VBA-generated worksheet comments produces an unwanted 'box' character at the end of every line in the resulting worksheet comments which are followed by another line (that is, the boxes are on every line of the comment except the last one).

Here is a sample of the VBA code that I'm using to create the text for the comment:

```
                    strCmnt = "Text for line 1 of comment"
                    strCmnt = strCmnt & vbCrLf & "Text for line 2 of comment"
                    strCmnt = strCmnt & vbCrLf & "Text for line 3 of comment"
```

The result is a line break after lines 1 and 2 in the comment box, as there should be, but a little box appears after the word "comment" on line 1 and line 2.

How do I retain the line breaks without producing the boxes?

Comment: I'm unable to replicate your issue.  Have you tried perhaps using `Chr(10)` instead of `vbCrLf`?

Comment: Couldn't replicate your issue. Post code where you actually create the comment?

Comment: EntryLevel, that did the trick. Thanks! I forgot to mention that this issue has only occurred for me in Excel 2010, not 2013. If you put your comment as the answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Does it happen in all fonts?

Comment: John, the default comment font in both the 2010 and 2013 installs that I'm using is Tahoma and I didn't change the font on either.

Comment: Normally within a comment box, the newline is just `vbLf`, not `vbCrLf`.

Comment: `Chr(10)` is `vbLf`. `vbLf` works better in Excel because it happens to be the new line character picked by the developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **`vbLf`** instead of `vbCrLf`, see screencap:

The `vbCrLf` has a block within the comment:
[image: sample_vbcrlf]

But if you use **`vbLf`** then:
[image: sample_vblf]

Comment: Thanks. I did already change my code to use Chr(10) instead of vbCrLF Chr(10), but vbLf is a still better choice.

Comment: `vbLf` is same as `Chr(10)`, but it's less typing and more neat. `?Asc(vbLf)` does give you `10`.

Comment: Yes, hence 'is a still better choice' even though their values are identical. Also, vbLf is a constant rather than a function of a constant, so there is that, too.